# my project is not creating folders after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, publish

when i test it on my local computer i used

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~/AppUploads/" + id_analisis + "/" + carpeta));
```

and it works fine, then i published it and tried it on iis 10 and it's just not working... any ideas?

i also modifield the Web.config file because maybe it could be a permisson...

```
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
    </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited the folder permisson of the project

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\

right click on my project's folder->Properties->Security->Edit->Add->Advanced Options->Search Now-> and select IIS_IUSRS, then i give it total control, i dont know if it's the best talking about security but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some permission problem, or after deploying the program can't find the right pat.

Check which user can access to the folder where you create the new dir

Leo